# How to hover on element using elementFromPoint method?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a windows simulator for android. I have already made my cursor using `canvas`. So, I want to use elementFromPoint method to hover on the element using the cursor.

```
// pos.x and pos.y are the co-ordinate of the cursor
canvas.style.display = "none";
let element = document.elementFromPoint(pos.x, pos.y);
// A method to activate the hover stage so that it could change its background
// like element.hover();
/* Code here */
canvas.style.display = "block";
```

It would be greatful if you help me.

Comment: It looks like you can already use inline styles, what prevents you to apply the same logic to the element `elementFromPoint` finds?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: I am asking for a method to activate the hover state of an element. Do you get it?

Comment: Umm ... the only "hover state" in _Windows_ changes the cursor icon according to the element type under the cursor, you're talking about changing background. A "hover state" is rather a web page specific effect, just do it like you'd do it on a web page, set the inline style or add a specific "hover" class to the element, for the class you'd have a rule in a stylesheet.

Comment: Can you give an example

Comment: I have tried focus() method but not working

Comment: ?? You already have an example in your own code: `canvas.style.display = "none";` Just apply it to `element` and set background property of the style.